# Fallback appender for Logback's SiftingAppender

Tags: java, logging, logback, sifting-appender

In the case of a `SiftingAppender` setup, is there a way to reference a fallback appender when the MDC key is set to the default value?

For instance, I want to use a file appender when the MDC key is set to a value that is different than the default, but log to the console when the MDC key is set to the default value.

The only solution I see right now is to subclass the `SiftingAppender` class and override the `append(E event)` logic to fallback to a default appender if the MDC key is set to the default value.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter your `SiftingAppender` and your `ConsoleAppender` with mutually exclusive conditions by using Logback [filters](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html).

Example filter declarations:

- Using Groovy to express the 'contains default MDC key' condition:

  ```
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
      <!-- GEventEvaluator requires Groovy -->
       <evaluator
          class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.GEventEvaluator">
         <expression>
           mdc.get("servicekey") == null
         </expression>
       </evaluator>
       <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
       <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
  </filter>
  ```
- Using Janino to express the 'contains default MDC key' condition:

  ```
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
       <!-- JaninoEventEvaluator requires Janino -->
       <evaluator
         class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
         <expression>
           mdc.get("yourMdcKey") == null
         </expression>
      </evaluator>
      <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
      <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
  </filter>
  ```

Assuming you choose the Janino filter then your appenders would be declared as follows::

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
         <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
           <expression>
             mdc.get("yourMdcKey") == null
           </expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
    </filter> 

    ...

</appender> 

<appender name="SIFTER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
         <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
           <expression>
             mdc.get("yourMdcKey") == null
           </expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
    </filter> 

    ...

</appender>
```

Note: in the above examples I have used `mdc.get("yourMdcKey") == null` / `mdc.get("yourMdcKey") != null` to express this conditional: *is the MDC key set to the default value?*. It's likely that your default value is not `null` but perhaps some populated value, if so then you would alter the conditional statement accordingly.

This approach allows you to declare a gate in front of your appenders and this gate applies the following test:

- For `FileAppender` if the MDC key is not populated then ignore the event otherwise accept the event
- For `SiftingAppender` if the MDC key is not populated then ignore the event otherwise accept the event

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped me getting this done here. I has to switch around the NEUTRAL and DENY on both filters though, since I want the SiftingAppender to run when the MDC contains a value. You write "For SiftingAppender if the MDC key is populated then accept the event otherwise ignore the event", you probably want to fix it as well.